# The property andCallThrough() does not exist on the value of type jasmine.spy

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
    it('should call getCompany on the people service when getCompany is called',

        function () {
            spyOn(peopleService, 'requestPeople').andCallThrough();

            scope.getCompany();

            deferred.resolve();

            scope.$root.$digest();

            expect(peopleService.requestPeople).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

    it('should populate the peopleList when getCompany is called',

        function () {
            scope.getCompany();

            deferred.resolve();

            scope.$root.$digest();

            expect(scope.peopleList).not.toBe([]);
        });
```

I'm having a piece of code that mockes the service but I'm getting the error 
as mentioned above.Any one faced the same issue?Any fixes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the version of Jasmine you are using.

`.andCallThrough()` is used in Jasmine 1.3, you should use `.and.callThrough()` in Jasmine 2.x